# In threading.thread, why does args take a comma at the end

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading

I am reading the multi-threading in python. When I come into code like below:

```
x = threading.Thread(target=thread_function, args=(1,))
```

I am a little bit confused why `args` is `(1,)` which takes a comma at the end. I have tested that if I remove the comma it won't work. But I kind of get confused what is the difference here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why your code doesn't work without the comma is that the `args` parameter must contain a tuple, and the common way of creating a single-element tuple is exactly like `(elem,)`.

If you remove the comma, the python interpreter will just ignore the parentheses and pass `1` as argument.