# TypeError: asyncio.runners.run() argument after * must be an iterable, not coroutine

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, discord.py, python-asyncio

i m trying to login to diffrent discord tokens from a file, and I'd like to multithread it for a faster way of doing it, but I get an error in asyncio, here is the code

```
f = open("tokens.txt", "r")
lines = f.readlines()
for line in lines:
    print(type(line), line)


async def hosting(token): 

        bot = discord.Client()
        await bot.login(token)
        print(f"Connected as: {token}")

async def do_something_important():
    await print(10)


if __name__ == "__main__":

  for token in lines:
    _thread = threading.Thread(target=asyncio.run, args=(hosting(token)))
    _thread.start()
```

and the traceback:

```
File "C:\Users\iuli2\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\threading.py", line 973, in _bootstrap_inner
  File "C:\Users\iuli2\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\threading.py", line 910, in run
  File "C:\Users\iuli2\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\threading.py", line 910, in run
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\iuli2\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\threading.py", line 973, in _bootstrap_inner
  File "C:\Users\iuli2\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\threading.py", line 973, in _bootstrap_inner
  File "C:\Users\iuli2\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\threading.py", line 973, in _bootstrap_inner
C:\Users\iuli2\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\threading.py:914: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'hosting' was never awaited
  del self._target, self._args, self._kwargs
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\iuli2\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\threading.py", line 910, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
TypeError: asyncio.runners.run() argument after * must be an iterable, not coroutine
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
TypeError: asyncio.runners.run() argument after * must be an iterable, not coroutine
```

Comment: Mixing asyncio and threading is not a really good idea, to run a coroutine in a separate thread use [`asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe)

Comment: @ŁukaszKwieciński I'm not sure what to pass in asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(coro, loop), what should i pass as courutine and loop to call my hosting function

Comment: `coro` would be `hosting(token)`, and `loop` -> the event loop

Comment: In addition to what was already said, note that `(hosting(token))` does not create an iterable. If you’re trying to make a tuple containing one item, you need to add a comma: `(hosting(token),)`. Either that or use a list instead.

Answer (score 0):

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59645272/how-do-i-pass-an-async-function-to-a-thread-target-in-python), it's required to have a comma after the first argument.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":

  for token in lines:
    _thread = threading.Thread(target=asyncio.run, args=(hosting(token),))
    _thread.start()
```

This is because [in Threads, args must be a tuple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67331204/in-threading-thread-why-does-args-take-a-comma-at-the-end). I'm also working on a discord bot and this answer worked.