# Question about _thread.start_new_thread method

Tags: python, python-multithreading

Why in this example we must put a comma after the pat and mat argument?
I searched several sites but did not find an answer

```
import _thread
import turtle
def f(painter):
    for i in range(3):
        painter.fd(50)
        painter.lt(60)
def g(painter):
    for i in range(3):
        painter.rt(60)
        painter.fd(50)
try:
    pat=turtle.Turtle()
    mat=turtle.Turtle()
    mat.seth(180)
    _thread.start_new_thread(f,(pat,))
    _thread.start_new_thread(g,(mat,))
    turtle.done()
except:
    pass
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In threading.thread, why does args take a comma at the end (duplicate)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67331204/6045800)

Answer (score 0):

Because its a tuple. Writing `(pat)` or `(mat)` is evaluated as part of an operation like `x * (y + z)`. Adding the comma allows the runtime to understand you're providing a tuple or an immutable list.

Comment: A tuple IS an immutable list. I edited the mathematical part. Removed the alternative, thanks.